# JMeter Http Request GET ignores parameters

Tags: jmeter, httprequest

In the JMeter [Documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) for HTTP Request  Samplers, I found this:

"As a special case, if the path starts with "`http://`" or "`https://`" then this is used as the full URL. In this case, the server, port and protocol fields are ignored; parameters are also ignored for `GET` and `DELETE` methods."

Does this mean that `GET` *always* ignores parameters or just in that special case? I would prefer to put my parameters in the 'send parameter with the request' section for legibility, but if it doesn't work, I don't want to waste time on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normall JMeter builds the full URL based on the details from server, Port, protocol, Path details of HTTP sampler OR HTTP Request Defaults assuming Path field contains only the path for the resource you are trying to access for the given server. In this case, JMeter, does not ignore parameters in 'send parameter with the request' section. You can add your parameters in 'send parameter with the request' section.

Comment: Yeah, make sure you put a 'HTTP Request Defaults' config element in your project.  That way, you wont need to specify the whole url.